# "Welcome to emergency mode" at boot after using NTFS-config

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

I had to format an external hard drive in NTFS; I then ran

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config ntfs-3g
sudo ntfs-config
```

to be able to write to it. Since then, I get the

> Welcome to emergency mode

message at boot. I am able to boot only when I plug in the external hard drive.

I then figured that I had probably messed with the fstab. I ran

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

getting the following result:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root :
UUID=1678cf7f-8077-4730-b3e5-11c960367afc   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=4e548c72-9070-4121-8e55-74db4a5edb1a   /boot   ext2    defaults    0   2
**#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=0801A6590A9ED79E   /media/username/HARDDRIVE   ntfs    defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222,nodev,nosuid   0   0**
#Entry for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 :
UUID=1ece0487-6f35-4651-869a-1e9f583d2a74   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Now, just to be sure: Am I right that I resolve this problem by deleting the following lines from my `/etc/fstab` (by deleting it with `gedit`)?

```
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=0801A6590A9ED79E   /media/username/HARDDRIVE   ntfs    defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222,nodev,nosuid   0   0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your exact setup, but you could just comment out this line by preceding it with `#` and try without deleting anything.

Comment: What @dessert says. `/etc/fstab` is just a mechanism to automatically mount what you can manually mount as well.

Comment: Yes, I understand - but what the command says it that "/media/username/HARDDRIVE ntfs" should be automatically mounted, right? And I am guessing that that is what causes the boot problem. I'll try as suggested!

Comment: OK, yes, that did it - I am now able to boot normally again. Thanks @dessert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a line in the `/etc/fstab` file became obsolete because of changes made to the system, it should be commented out by preceding it with a number sign `#`:

```
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
#UUID=0801A6590A9ED79E   /media/username/HARDDRIVE   ntfs    defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222,nodev,nosuid   0   0
```

This way it will be ignored on the next boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the external to auto mount when connected, but ignored when not connected, add `nofail` to the options
ie.

```
#Entry for /dev/sdb2  
UUID=0801A6590A9ED79E   /media/username/HARDDRIVE   ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=0222,nodev,nosuid,nofail   0   0
```